# Angular 8 - Pegar atributos no retorno do serviço API. httpClient

Tags: angular, typescript

Preciso de ajuda de como manipular os atributos que estão sendo retornado da minha API. Quero interceptá-los na minha classe service, mais não estou conseguindo usando o Subscribe.

export class LancamentoService {

```
  lancamentoUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/lancamentos';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  pesquisar(filtro: any): Observable<Lancamento> {
    let params = new HttpParams();

    params = params.set('page', filtro.pagina);
    params = params.set('size', filtro.itensPorPagina);

    if (filtro.descricao) {
      params = params.set('descricao', filtro.descricao);
    }

    if (filtro.dataVencimentoInicio) {
      params = params.set('dataVencimentoDe', moment(filtro.dataVencimentoInicio).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    }

    if (filtro.dataVencimentoFim) {
      params = params.set('dataVencimentoAte', moment(filtro.dataVencimentoFim).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    }

    return this.http.get<Lancamento>(`${this.lancamentoUrl}?resumo`, { params } );

  }
```

Demarquei os atributos que eu quero manipular.

https://ibb.co/vqsdXGL

Comment: Tive que editar minha resposta rs, você mudou a sua pergunta 3x hahah

Comment: Desculpa, é a primeira vez que eu estou buscando ajuda no stack.

Comment: Sem problemas, veja se a minha resposta te ajuda, sempre que precisar pode buscar a comunidade, caso não comente lá na resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, eu vou dar uma olhada na documentação do RxJS que me mandou o link e caso eu não conseguir eu retorno aqui.

Comment: Eu dei um exemplo usando o pipe com map no service, acho que resolve seu problema

Answer (score 1):

Certo, você quer pegar o retorno desse Observable get, você pode usar um callback e escutar esse metodo usando um subscribe, seria bom você dar uma olhada na documentação e entender como funciona o Observable rxjs, e ver como funciona em Angular.

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(
 private lancamentoService: LancamentoService ) { }

 ngOnInit() {
  // se você precisar que chame no ciclo de vida, adicionar aqui
 }

 pesquisarLancamentos() {
  this.lancamentoService.pesquisar().subscribe(res => {
    // res retorno do pesquisar
  });

 }
}
```

e pra pegar apenas os atributos igual da imagem, você pode usar um pipe e map, e no call back do component você ainda vai continuar usando o subscribe pra pegar o retorno.

```
return this.http.get<Lancamento>(`${this.lancamentoUrl}?resumo`, { params } ).pipe(map(res => // mapear seus atributos aqui
));
```

https://angular.io/guide/observables
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable